# How to stop CentOS Desktop from going to sleep due to inactivity?

Tags: centos

so I am having trouble with preventing my desktop from going to sleep when I leave it overnight. I am running calculations that take several hours and whenever my computer goes to sleep, the calculations are interrupted. I am running CentOS 6.5.

I have already when to System > Preferences > Power Management and changed settings to Never  and Never for the AC Power tab.

I've also tried it through terminal:

```
[------]$ sudo setterm -powersave off -blank 0 
cannot (un)set powersave mode
```

However, after 10-15 minutes, my monitor still goes to sleep and I will have to retype my password to get back in. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so what needs to be done is to go to System > Preferences > Screen Saver and then uncheck the box that reads "Activate Screen Saver when Computer is Idle". This should solve the problem.

If it still blanks the screen, I find that in CentOs 7 I also have to go into system->users->myuseraccount and set Automatic Login to On or the system locks even when screen blank is never and suspend is set to off.

The system log "messages" shows 
systemd[1] : Removed slice *usernameredacted​*.slice.
systemd[1] : Stopping *usernameredacted*.slice.
at the time the screen blanked.

Answer (score 12):

Or System > Preferences > Power Management > On Battery Power tab > Put display to sleep when inactive for: NEVER!